# how to open a url in safari instead of opening its installed app in Ios?

Tags: swift, api, redirect, swiftui

so, I'm using Goodreads API to auth purposes in my ios app. the problem happens when the user has Goodreads app installed in his iPhone. the iPhone goes directly to Goodreads app and (gets stuck) instead of opening Safari and authenticate through it.

so, I want to prevent the iPhone from redirecting to Goodreads App and to open the URL in safari and to authenticate through it.

note: when I delete Goodreads app installed in my iPhone everything works fine.

[here's what happens when I try my app and I have installed Goodreads app. it keeps loading forever.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap8BZ.png)

Comment: Sounds like it's working the way it should, because when the Goodreads app is installed you get all of the Associated Domains that come with the Goodreads app.  So when you try to visit one of those domains it's being helpful by taking you to the app.

Comment: Okay. But this means that the goodreads app has an issue when a third-party app tries to authenticate through it. What should i do?

Comment: It appears it's an issue will have to take up with the Goodreads as they seem to have forgot to exclude the `/oauth/authorise` from app links.  [Broken OAuth on iOS with official Goodreads app installed](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/20897222-broken-oauth-on-ios-with-official-goodreads-app-installed)